# Jquery fade one id at a time

Tags: jquery, html

I am new to Jquery and I am developing some online tutorials. In each tutorial, I want each stage to fade in one at a time when you click the next button and then when you have shown the last stage the next button should hide and a new next button, when clicked, should take you to the next tutorial. I am using ids to assign paragraphs in my HTML. As I am doing lots of tutorials with different numbers of steps in each, I would like to easily change this code according to the number of steps in each tutorial. I have tried to code this, and, although my code does what I want it to, it is very messy and long and I think there must be a shorter way.
Here is my HTML:

```
<div>
<p id="text1">Step one goes here</p>
<p id="text2">Step two goes here</p>
<p id="text3">Step three goes here</p>
<p id="nextstep"><a href="#">Next Step</a></p>
<p id="nexttut"><a href="tutorial2.html">Next Tutorial</a></p>
</div>
```

Thanks
EDIT: I only want to use HTML and Javascript

Comment: You can use php to di this with a loop.

Comment: what have you tried, your javascript? a demo fiddle or codepen or jsbin would be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways you could achieve this with jQuery, mainly depending on how "magical" you want to be.

One fairly simple strategy would be to have a global variable called stepNumber, and a data attribute on your steps, like so:

```js
var stepNumber = 1;

$(function(){
  $('p[data-step-id="' + stepNumber + '"]').show();
  
  $('#nextstep').click(function(){
    $('p[data-step-id="' + stepNumber++ + '"]').fadeOut();
    $('p[data-step-id="' + stepNumber + '"]').fadeIn();
  });
});
```

```css
.step {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<p id="text1" class="step" data-step-id="1">Step one goes here</p>
<p id="text2" class="step" data-step-id="2">Step two goes here</p>
<p id="text3" class="step" data-step-id="3">Step three goes here</p>
<p id="nextstep"><a href="#">Next Step</a></p>
<p id="nexttut"><a href="tutorial2.html">Next Tutorial</a></p>
</div>
```

This approach is quite agnostic of the structure of your steps - they don't even have to be in the right order. Your step IDs are not required in this approach.

*However,*

We could simplify this by assuming that the steps are in order. We can use the `nth-child` CSS selector to find the next step, and we can compare this to the number of steps to see if we should display the Next Tutorial button again.

As with the first approach, the step IDs are not actually used.

```js
var stepNumber = 1;

$(function(){
  $('p.step:nth-child(' + stepNumber + ')').show();
  
  $('#nextstep').click(function(){
    $('p.step:nth-child(' + stepNumber++ + ')').fadeOut();
    $('p.step:nth-child(' + stepNumber + ')').fadeIn();
    if(stepNumber == $('p.step').length) {
      $('#nextstep').hide();
      $('#nexttut').show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.step, #nexttut {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<p id="text1" class="step">Step one goes here</p>
<p id="text2" class="step">Step two goes here</p>
<p id="text3" class="step">Step three goes here</p>
<p id="nextstep"><a href="#">Next Step</a></p>
<p id="nexttut"><a href="tutorial2.html">Next Tutorial</a></p>
</div>
```

In both cases I've given the steps a common CSS class so that they can be easily identified in the Javascript.

Comment: I like your second approach. How do I make it so that each step stays on screen instead of going when you bring in the next step?

Comment: Thanks! Just remove the line that fades out the current step. Then, you may wish to scroll the page to the new one. I'm on my phone so I'm not going to describe that part in detail, but you can do a nice smooth scroll to an element with jQuery.

Comment: I am trying to insert an image in one of my steps, how would I go about making that fade in with the text whn that step comes up? I have tried inserting it into the <p> tag but it shows at the start when the text doesn't. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: That's interesting, I would expect the image to be inline with the text by default. Anyway though, you might want to change the p tags to divs, within which you can have paragraphs, images, whatever you want and style it however you like.

Comment: I got <p> to contain the inline image in the end. I have some other classes for that image (w3-image w3-col m12 l3) for my image to make it responsive and it seems to clear the class (step) from the parent <p>. I put step in the class (step w3-image w3-col m12 l3) and it makes the image come up seperately How do I make it come up with the text in the parent <p> tag? Any help, or is that not possibe? Also, If I want to use <ul>s instead of <p>s how would the code change?

Answer (score 1):

You could look up the `id` using `[id^="text"]` which looks for ids starting with text. and use `:hidden` to check if anymore need fading in. if there is then fade in `:first`, else fade in the next tutorial.

```js
$('#nextstep').click(function() {
  if ($('[id^="text"]:hidden').length) {
    $('[id^="text"]:hidden:first').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('#nexttut').fadeIn();
    $(this).fadeOut();
  }
})
```

```css
[id^=text],
#nexttut {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <p id="text1">Step one goes here</p>
  <p id="text2">Step two goes here</p>
  <p id="text3">Step three goes here</p>
  <p id="nextstep"><a href="#">Next Step</a>
  </p>
  <p id="nexttut"><a href="tutorial2.html">Next Tutorial</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: That's great. Thanks. Do you know how I would hide nextstep when nexttut appears?